# Can someone explain the below code for deep copy of an object?

Tags: javascript

I saw the below code on how to deep copy objects in JavaScript. But I'm unable to understand few things in this code.

```
function clone(obj) {
    if (obj === null || typeof (obj) !== 'object' || 'isActiveClone' in obj)
        return obj;

    if (obj instanceof Date)
        var temp = new obj.constructor(); //or new Date(obj);
    else
        var temp = obj.constructor();

    for (var key in obj) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) {
            obj['isActiveClone'] = null;
            temp[key] = clone(obj[key]);
            delete obj['isActiveClone'];
        }
    }
    return temp;
 }
```

Let me explain this code based on my understanding. First thing we do is check if object is `null` or not an object or `isEmpty` using a loop `'isActiveClone' in obj` if any of these fails we return the object.
Now, we check if the object is a Date object if yes, I'm unable to understand new `obj.constructor();` and `var temp = obj.constructor();` What are we doing here?

Then, we run a loop over our object. If a `key` is present in obj using `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)`. Then I do not understand   `obj['isActiveClone'] = null;` and `delete obj['isActiveClone'];`. In line  `temp[key] = clone(obj[key]);` we are recursively calling our function to deal with nestedness in the object. At the end we are returning `temp` which will be the deep copy of object.

Comment: "What are we doing here?" - calling a constructor. Do you have any **specific** question about that code?

Comment: Also, you could check what specific lines do by removing them and cloning an object. Probably you could spot differences between a cloned object from the original and the modified code?

Comment: @NicoHaase Why? Are we creating an empty object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running .constructor is going to construct your object that you are cloning. The new keyword is a special case. There might be more times you want to check for it (for instance, if you have custom classes that use a new-able constructor), but for deep copying generic json objects and dates, this works.

As far as I can tell, deleting the key "isActiveClone" where the delete statement is located doesn't accomplish anything. That is code that will never be reached if the "isActiveClone" key is present in the given object. In the first line of the function, it returns immediately if obj contains the isActiveClone key, so logically, the code should never reach the delete statement when there is anything to delete. Additionally, setting the "isActiveClone" key to null at the beginning of the loop isn't accomplishing anything either and runs every iteration of the loop. It would increase efficiency and readability to remove those lines.

Comment: Looks like `isActiveClone` prevents self or ancestor copies. The function is recursive and uses the key existence as a flag.

Comment: @Ouroborus If I remove `isActiveClone` can you tell the edge cases where the code will fail?

Comment: Why are we doing `hasOwnProperty` check? If we run a loop on object wouldn't it only iterate the available keys? Then why this check?

Comment: Without `isActiveClone`, something like `x = {}; x.self = x; y = clone(x)` would be a problem. The `hasOwnProperty` check prevents inherited properties from being included in the copy.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) license, for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted.